# iOS Facebook SDK Signup Multiple Users without Caching

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

The app I'm working on will be used to sign multiple people up to a service using their Facebook/Google accounts - imagine a kiosk at some event with iPads to demo a product and sign users up.

I've done plenty with social sign in before, but its always under the assumption that they are signing up with our app on *their* device, so they probably have the Facebook app installed already and even if not they can log in when the Facebook SDK switches them over to Safari and they login there.

The major issue I'm running into now is Safari and caching. When users hit the "sign up with Facebook" button they're sent over to safari where they put in their fb credentials, authorize us for various permissions, and are then sent back to our app. The problem is when the next person comes to sign up, safari has their info cached so it just says "you've already authorized this app" for the person *before*. We obviously don't want to keep people logged in to Facebook after they sign up, and we really don't want to have to ***manually log every user out*** of Facebook in safari after they sign up...

I've tried using safari's private browsing, which when run on the simulator every new user that hits sign up with Facebook is taken to the fb login screen in safari, but not on real devices where they are again taken to the "already authorized" page.

Essentially we want to be able to sign up multiple users back to back with our system with their Facebook accounts - keeping in mind that we have no control over Safari or the Facebook app and how they store sign-in status/info during this process. Does anyone know any work arounds?